# Apache Error log with connection to paypal

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I have just been looking though my apache error logs when I have come across this a number of times. Can anybody explain if this something I should be worried about?

```
[Wed Aug 10 21:37:41 2011] [error] [client 122.173.59.145] File does not exist: /var/www/site/public/templates, referer: http://3gparena.org/showmovie.php?id=123
* About to connect() to www.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 66.211.169.74... * connected
* Connected to www.paypal.com (66.211.169.74) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: /1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/2.5.4.15=Private Organization/serialNumber=3014267/C=US/postalCode=95131-2021/ST=California/L=San Jose/streetAddress=2211 N 1st St/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=www.paypal.com
*    start date: 2011-03-23 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2013-04-01 23:59:59 GMT
*    common name: www.paypal.com (matched)
*    issuer: /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
* SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 1200
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2011 20:37:29 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=gu4n4JIQNLNKHwLGrmJY52DqtqKoc9twOQnBaeoRnNnqXLOaQ-ZKROUKqwpZlLOtoazhkysKk79OrriHHuyFJT4zhTjtHhjl3NiH-m784LImEFup03Uf0ZnShUZ2u0fzdJx0xm%7c8iWLdxQcgk7jSwQzS4WbIQvUvQq429z8blmNjAvbQMCyHkBYoW9K0PDymH-YQHrlTNCDIm%7cAWgU_l3tl_YtRQOuEXlxanu-J9WTXhjVgIeiujllveuBaTH5tMiAwu5hm8nD7uUmmFVGbW%7c1313008650; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Sat, 07-Aug-2021 20:37:30 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Tue, 05-Aug-2031 20:37:30 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: Apache=10.190.9.187.1313008649452817; path=/; expires=Fri, 02-Aug-41 20:37:29 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=500
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.paypal.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: That's a paypal API call.  Should it be doing that?  If not, then yeah, you should be worried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345270/headers-are-showing-up-in-apache-error-log-curl-and-paypal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Paypal API calls.  Provided you have a web-app doing so (php or something) it should be OK...

edit:  Looks like @Shane's comment beat me ;)

Comment: After looking into this further I found that yes a paypal payment was made at this time. So no problem even though this is in the error log?